# PowerBi DAX write DAX to compare date time

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to set a column value before 2021-1-20 as 0. So I need to compare date time in data. Here is my wrong code.

```
ColumnValue = IF([MyDate]>="1/20/2021",
SWITCH([Key],
"caseA",[Value],
"caseB",[Value],
"caseC",[Value],
"caseD",-1*[Value],
"caseE",-1*[Value],
0
),0)
```

However, it hints that DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Date with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values. But I don't know how to compare DAX date time.

Answer (score 2):

you can write the date as a text using the `yyyy-mm-dd` format and then use `VALUE` like follows

```
ColumnValue =
IF(
    [MyDate] >= VALUE( "2021-01-20" ),
    SWITCH(
        [Key],
        "caseA", [Value],
        "caseB", [Value],
        "caseC", [Value],
        "caseD", -1 * [Value],
        "caseE", -1 * [Value],
        0
    ),
    0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is, it is comparing date with text data type, you need to pass matching value in date format, for which you can use the following function

```
ColumnValue = IF([MyDate] >= dt"1/20/2021",
SWITCH([Key],
"caseA",[Value],
"caseB",[Value],
"caseC",[Value],
"caseD",-1*[Value],
"caseE",-1*[Value],
0
),0)

or 

ColumnValue = IF([MyDate] >= date(2021,01,20),
SWITCH([Key],
"caseA",[Value],
"caseB",[Value],
"caseC",[Value],
"caseD",-1*[Value],
"caseE",-1*[Value],
0
),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I already know the answer, by using DATEDIFF

```
ColumnValue = IF(DATEDIFF(DATE(2021,1,20),[MyDate],DAY)>=0,
SWITCH([Key],
"caseA",[Value],
"caseB",[Value],
"caseC",[Value],
"caseD",-1*[Value],
"caseE",-1*[Value],
0
),0)
```